# Use RMSSE as loss function in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

How to use RMSSE below to build a loss function in `model.compile()`?

[image]

Below is what I'm trying to do

```
import keras.backend as k

def rmsse(y_true, y_pred):
    h = 28
    n = 1885

    numerator = k.sum(k.square(y_true[1885:] - y_pred))
    denominator = 1/(n-1)*k.sum(k.square(y_true[1:1885] - t_true[0:1884]))

    rmsse = k.square(1/h * numerator/denominator)
    return rmsse

#compile model using rmsse as a measure of model performance
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss= rmsse, metrics = 'accuracy')
```

However, when I applied this to my `model.compile` function, it showed

```
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Sub' Op has type float32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'x'
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Problem is that your y_true or y_pred are integers and floats are expected.